# Java compatiblity with older version's bytecode

Tags: java, compilation, compatibility

This is a question about Java version compatibility, which I know has been asked before, but from a slightly different angle. Previous answers I've seen suggest compiling the older version java code in the higher version of Java, like:

javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 MyJavaFile.java.

However, I'm not clear whether if I have bytecode previously compiled  under the older version of Java, e.g 1.5, will it run happily in e.g. a Java 6 or 7 environment, or is it a requirement to recompile under the later version of Java, as above?

Thanks!

Comment: if it's compiled with Java 5 it should run fine with JRE 6 or 7 (except that JRE 6 or 7 may have fixed bugs / make changes that will bread the original code).

Comment: You could always try it yourself and see...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266940/is-java-bytecode-compatible-with-different-versions-of-java?rq=1

Comment: In general, yes, if you have a Java .class file compiled on an older Java version it will run without difficulty on a newer version.  There may be a handful of odd exceptions, but nothing likely to bite you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Unfortunately, RedFive, we are talking massive enterprise banking apps, so can't just load them up on my laptop! ;-)